# Receive error on reading json data : new_mongo_booksearch.php:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property

Tags: javascript

I receive this error. 
I create a  mongodb cursor in PHP convert to JSON,
I want to use the JSON data in Javascript

new_mongo_booksearch.php:18 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'description' of undefined'

I have seen this error all over this site but those scenarios are not the same.

---

```
<?php

     // connect to mongodb
   $m = new MongoClient();
     // select a database
   $db = $m->testdata;

   $collection = new MongoCollection($db, 'googlebooks');

   $query = array('volumeInfo.title' => 'Analysis');

   $cursor = $collection->find($query);
   $jsonfile = json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor, false), true);
  // echo $jsonfile;
   // iterate cursor to display title of documents   
    ?>

    <script>
    $(function(){
        //dump json file content to a JavaScript JSON object
       // var json = <?php echo json_encode(iterator_to_array($cursor)); ?>;
        var json = <?php echo $jsonfile; ?>;

        var description = "";



    //  console.log(json.volumeInfo);
              description =  json.volumeInfo.description;
            //echo(description);
            //var title =  json.volumeInfo;
            //var url = json.volumeInfo;
            //var cover = json.volumeInfo;

            //$("#cover").attr("src",cover);
            //$("#title").text(title);
            //$("#description").text(description);
            //$("#webpage").text(url).attr("href",url);

            document.getElementById("description").innerHTML = description;

            var resultHTML="";
            for (i in json.volumeInfo)
                {
                    resultHTML+="<br>"+json.volumeInfo;
                }
                $("#category").html(resultHTML); 
        });
```

[image]

Comment: The error is in the JavaScript and not the PHP code going by your "screenshot" ( from which you should have included that code as text and not the other listing ). the `var json = [...]` declares an "array" and not an object. You need to iterate each array member to access the `Object` properties.

Comment: thank you Blakes ! After I iterated the data in the array it worked.